# Recognize "space" and "enter" with scanf C

Tags: c

I need to recognize if a character taken as input is SPACE or ENTER.
I know that enter is "0x0A" as hexadecimal while space is "0x20" but I don't kown why scanf seems to not recognize space.

```
while ( (error=scanf("%d", &stop) )== EOF && error==0 )
  printf("Error while reading the value input, try again\n");
...(some code)...
while ( stop!= 0x0A )
{
    if (stop == 0x20) {
        printf("Going to fill the line\n");
    ...(some code)...
 }
```

With the 1st "while" I want that the user inserts a generic value, in the 2nd I check if the value was "ENTER" and the "if" checks if "SPACE" has been inserted.
If I press "SPACE" there's a segmentation fault, don't know why :S

EDIT :

I wrote this new example from what I read in comments :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char input;
    int error =0;
    printf("I want to read only numbers\n" 
        "Let's start!\n");
    while ( (error=scanf("%c", &input) )== EOF || error==0 )
        printf("Error while reading the input, maybe Enter was pressed try again\n");
        printf("input is : %c \n",input);
        printf("Taking new input : \n");
   while (input != "\n")
   {
       if (input == 0x20)
          break;
          printf("Taking New input : \n");
       while ( (error=scanf("%c", &input) )== EOF || error==0 )
        printf("Error while reading the input, maybe Enter was pressed try again\n");
        printf("New input is : %c \n",input);
   }
   return;
}
```

this is the output :

```
I want to read only numbers
Let's start!
7
input is : 7 
Taking New input : 
New input is :
```

And the program ends.

Comment: Well, format `%d` format spec *filters* whitespace. Try `%c`.

Comment: Note that, as the `EOF` constant will **not** be defined as zero (normally, it's -1), then `error` (in your first `while`) cannot be both `EOF` && `0`.

Comment: @AdrianMole So I have to use "||" instead "&&"

Comment: If you need to know about white space, don't use `scanf()` and family.  They skip white space unless you're using `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets), or `%n`.

Comment: Thanks guys but I have some troubles, I don't understand what to do to fix it...I'm gonna do an other example.

Comment: regarding; `while ( (error=scanf("%d", &stop) )== EOF && error==0 )`  the contents of `error` cannot be both EOF and 0..  Therefore the body of that `while()` statement will never be executed

Comment: `error = scanf(` is *very* odd.  `scanf` returns the number of matched entries, so you would expect `scanf("%d",..)` to return 1 in normal operation.

Comment: regarding: *I know that enter is "0x0A"   This is not necessarily true.  If you want to check for a 'enter' key, then use '\n';  because  the result of hitting the 'enter' key differs between OSs

Comment: I suggest you use ```%c``` because ```%d``` maybe skips lots of white space.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d", &stop)`  The `%d` skips spaces and newlines (aka 'white space')

Comment: regarding: `while ( stop!= 0x0A )
{
    if (stop == 0x20) {`  Since `stop` contains an integer (due to the %d)  containing `0x0A` means the user entered decimal `10`.  Similarly if `stop` contains `0x20` then the user entered 32

Comment: what is the declaration of `stop`?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it,

Comment: @user3629249 Is this new example good?

Comment: Please do NOT modify the posted code.  Modification makes the prior comments 'nonsense' .  Instead, add a 'EDIT' section to the posted code that contains the modified code

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, I added an "Edit" section with a new code below

Comment: `while ( (error=scanf("%c", &input) )== EOF || error==0 )
        printf("Error while reading the input, maybe Enter was pressed try again\n");` is an infinite loop when end-of-file occurs.  Should break out of the loop on end-of-file.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ok but why scanf isn't triggered for each iteration?

Comment: @FinleyAdams  "triggered" is unclear.  `scanf("%c", &input)` executes each iteration.  On end-of-file condition, it repeatedly return `EOF`.

Comment: I don't understand why but I got you @chux-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why scanf seems to not recognize space.

`scanf()` can recognized spaces, but *not*
readily using `scanf("%d", &stop)` as `"%d"` first consumes and discards all leading white-space.

`"%c"` does not discard leading whitespace.  One character is read.

---

As OP seems interested in reading and testing a single character one at a time using `scanf()`, along with detecting a rare input error and maybe end-of-file:

```
// Read one character.
// Return 1 on success.
// Return EOF on end-of-file.
// Return 0 on rare input error.
int read1(char *dest) {
  if (scanf("%c", dest) == 1) return 1;
  if (feof(stdin)) return EOF;
  return 0;
}
```

---

> need to recognize if a character taken as input is SPACE or ENTER

`fgets()` is a *much* better approach to read a *line* of user input.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  // Use buf
}
```

Comment: I need only to read one character but thanks maybe I will use it in the future! And What the 3rd line does?

Comment: @FinleyAdams Unclear about "3rd line".  Which line? Perhaps copy/paste in comment

Comment: This one : if (feof(stdin)) return EOF;

Comment: @FinleyAdams When input functions return `EOF`, it is due to an _input error_ (e.g. keyboard died), end-of-file had occurred before, end-of-file just occurred.  `feof(stdin)` returns non-zero, (true),  in the latter 2 cases.

Comment: Ok thanks, btw your function ends with a bus error, I gave it as input "char *input" like : read1(input)

Comment: @FinleyAdams Save time, enable all warnings.  `int read1(char *dest); .... char input;  read1(input);` should complain.